# How to define a \citewithabstract in kaobook to print BibLaTeX "abstract" content in the Bibliography chapter

Tags: biblatex, kaobook

```
@Book{Schouten2001,
abstract = {... De Natuur Als Beeld In Religie, Filosofie En Kunst eerste druk is een boek van M.G.C. Schouten uitgegeven bij Knnv Uitgeverij. 
Er is tastbare natuur: de concrete werkelijkheid van aarde, rots, water, planten en dieren, die we kunnen zien, die we kunnen aanraken, van de landschappen waarin we kunnen wandelen. En er is ook ons beeld van de natuur. In onze beleving van de natuur maken we haar tot drager van onze mythen, symbolen en herinneringen, tot spiegel van onze emoties. ... $\backslash$n},
author = {M.G.C. Schouten},
booktitle = {De natuur als beeld in religie, filosofie en kunst},
isbn = {978-90-5011-206-4},
title = {De natuur als beeld in religie, filosofie en kunst},
%publisher = {KNNV Uitgeverij},
url = {http://www.google.com},
%2001
year = {2001}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please add a minimal example that reproduces your problem: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography, thank you!

Comment: What exactly is your aim here? I.e. why do you talk about a special command `\citewithabstract`? It would be fairly easy to have the `abstract` field shown for all entries in the bibligraphy, but then a special command would not make sense. Do you want the `abstract` only shown for some entries?

Answer (score 3):

If you put the abstract information in a field called `note`, it will be printed with the citation. For instance:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=apa, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\bibliography{bron.bib}
\addbibresource{bron.bib}

\begin{filecontents*}{bron.bib}
    @book{schouten2001,
        note  = {... De Natuur Als Beeld In Religie, Filosofie En Kunst eerste druk is een boek van M.G.C. Schouten uitgegeven bij Knnv Uitgeverij. 
        Er is tastbare natuur: de concrete werkelijkheid van aarde, rots, water, planten en dieren, die we kunnen zien, die we kunnen aanraken, van de landschappen waarin we kunnen wandelen. En er is ook ons beeld van de natuur. In onze beleving van de natuur maken we haar tot drager van onze mythen, symbolen en herinneringen, tot spiegel van onze emoties. ... $\backslash$n},
        author  = {Schouten, M. G. C.},
        booktitle = {De natuur als beeld in religie, filosofie en kunst},
        isbn  = {978-90-5011-206-4},
        title = {De natuur als beeld in religie, filosofie en kunst},
        %publisher = {KNNV Uitgeverij},
        url = {http://www.google.com},
        %2001
        year = {2001}
    }
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
Sentence with \textcite{schouten2001}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

It will work the same for your document class.

[image]

Comment: Thank You very much, it's working perfectly!

Comment: Happy to hear that! You can accept my answer by clicking the check mark at left.